# PHP: Find highest index of numeric array that has missing elements

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have the following array:

```
$n[5] = "hello";
$n[10]= "goodbye";`
```

I would like to find out the highest index of this array.
In Javascript, I could do `$n.length - 1` which would return `10`.
In PHP, though, `count($n)` returns 2, which is the number of elements in the array.

So how to get the highest index of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [max()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) and [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

```
echo max(array_keys($n));
```

Output:-https://eval.in/997652

Comment: Thanks! If there is no way to do it with a single command, this will do.

Comment: array_keys is 1 command, then max is 2. So this is 2 steps (in a single line), where Javascript does it in one: `[].length`. No hassle, just interesting difference for me between php and javascript.

Comment: @Ariel  then i can say that `$n.length` is one step and `-1`  from it will second step. :):)

Comment: True. But usually this is going to be useful in a loop, in which case: `for (i = 0; i < n.length; i++)`.... so only 1 step ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$n = [];
$n[5] = "hello";
$n[10]= "goodbye";

// get the list of key
$keyList = array_keys($n);

// get the biggest key
$maxIndex = max($keyList);

echo $n[$maxIndex];
```

output

```
goodbye
```